# Offline decompiler for Flash to get the ActionScript

Tags: decompiler, offline, flash

Hi I have tried quite a few decompilers for Flash but they do not work well, either generating unnecessary codes or even fail to decompile. The best currently that I found - and have been using - is showmycode, absolutely great result, but that is online, who knows if they will end their service any moment.

Please recommend an offline decompiler for Flash to get the ActionScript (I dont care about the Flash resources) that is on par with showmycode. Any platform will do, just not online. Best if you can point me to the software that is used by showmycode.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Specifically I'd suggest answering: What OS(es)? and What price range is acceptable?